# Trying to access my user account notes through my dev account

Tags: evernote

I want to get all my notes from my existing account and process them as following: the first row of every note has the timestamp of that note and I want to extract the timestamp and update the "created" field in the note's info according to it's timestamp.

The problem is that, when getting all notes from the api, it accesses the dev account instead of the user account, which is understandable.

Is it posible to log in to my user account from my dev account using the api and then get all the notes and modify them?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a developer token issued for sandbox.evernote.com. If you need to access your actual account, you need to get a separate token on the production service (https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action) and use it against production userstore and notestore.

Comment: I went to that link and it says: _Update: the creation of developer tokens is temporarily disabled._ Have any idea how long are they going to be disabled for?

Comment: @ArhireIonut That's strange. This link works for me just fine, and I'm able to create a developer token for myself. Try it one more time, and if it still doesn't, please send an email to devsupport at evernote dot com with the screenshot of the page you see, and we'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I sent an email and am waiting for a response.